# Time constant of inverting amplifier, filter

Tags: inverting-amplifier, time-constant

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fes0zi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want to calculate the time constant τ of the filter. Can anybody help me?

Comment: If you are familiar with using the Laplace transform to represent impedances, you can calculate the transfer function by dividing R2 by the parallel equivalent of R1 and 1/sC1. You will realize that the gain will be relatively flat till a certain cutoff frequency (I'll let you determine it) and then it will start growing at 20dB/dec after that.

Comment: Nodal analysis at the inverting input will give the TF.

Comment: I am familiar with the laplace transformation, but it seems like the transferfunction has no zeros. I end up with the following: R2 * ( C * s * R1 + 1)/R1

Comment: If you want the time constant of this circuit, reduce the input voltage to 0 V (replace the source by a short circuit) then disconnect capacitor \$C_1\$ and determine the resistance "seen" from its connections. That resistance multiplied by \$C_1\$ is your time constant while the inverse gives the pole. More details in this APEC seminar: http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf

Comment: Verbal Klint-I think, in your answer it would be helpful to mention if the opamp is to be considered as active or not.

Comment: In this problem the opamp is considered active. How does this change things?

Comment: The TF has no poles, it has one zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this circuit by considering its time constant is the right way to go. This is actually the basis for the fast analytical techniques or [FACTs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371). In the considered circuit, set \$s=0\$ (open the capacitor) and determine the gain linking \$V_{in}\$ to \$V_{out}\$ as illustrated in sketch (b) below. Considering a perfect op-amp, the dc gain is immediate and equal to:

\$G_0=-\frac{R_2}{R_1}\$

To determine the time constant of this circuit, simply reduce the excitation to 0 and "look" at the resistance offered by \$C_1\$'s connecting terminals as shown in sketch (c). In this drawing, zeroing the excitation to 0 V is similar to replacing the source by a short circuit. In this mode, again considering a perfect op-amp, the left connection of \$C_1\$ is grounded while the right-one, considering the virtual ground, is also 0 V. The time constant is thus:

\$\tau=0\times C_1 = 0\$ implying that there is no pole in this circuit. Actually, there is one and it is coming from the op-amp but it is not set by the external components.

For the zero, what condition would imply that the stimulus would not propagate through the circuit to form a response at \$s=s_z\$? Well, if the parallel combination of \$C_1\$ and \$R_1\$ offers an infinite impedance, there is no response. An impedance becomes infinite when its denominator \$D(s)\$ equals zero. In other words, what is the pole of \$Z_1\$? It is the resistance \$R_1\$. The zero is located at:

\$\omega_z=\frac{1}{R_1C_1}\$ and our transfer function is:

\$G(s)=G_0(1+\frac{s}{\omega_z})\$

[image]

The Mathcad file is there:

[image]